# rails time demon in my machine... it eats 2 hours have checked everything!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, utc

I have my checked my environment.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Prague'
```

Nothing in development.rb regarding time

This seems to work, in theory...

```
Time.zone.now # Thu, 10 Sep 2009 17:51:35 CEST +02:00
```

also correct...

```
Time.now # Thu Sep 10 17:52:10 +0200 2009

mysql... SELECT NOW() # 2009-09-10 17:53:48
```

correct!

but when I create a new record in rails or update an old one

```
Item.create(:price => price, :spots => beds) # 2009-09-10 15:55:28
```

and have restarted rails many many times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is saving it in UTC (GMT time), which is two hours earlier than your local time.  To a large extent creation times are better stored in UTC --> you then translate them upon viewing.

EDIT:  The [Timestamp class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html) seems to indicate that the local timestamp is supposed to be used.  You may want to check the setting the documentation indicates.

Comment: I tried putting 'UTC+2', 'UTC +02:00' but when loading rails via console it gave me errors.

Answer (score 0):

What is the time if you select that record via the console? 15:55 or 17:55?

If you select via the console it uses the timezone that is set, so naturally it will be different from the "real" timestamp in the mysql database.

Take a look at [Weird time inconsistencies between production and development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416294/weird-time-inconsistencies-between-production-and-development/1426961) as well.